# Limit involving positive random variable with finite moment

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we have positive random variable with property $EX^{r}<\infty$, where $r\in(0,1)$. Prove that $\lim_{t\to\infty}t^rP\{X>t\}=0$.

I tried thinking of the fact that $EX^r = \int_0^\infty rt^{r-1}P\{X>t\}dt$, but that didn't get me anywhere, because from this I can only make a conclusion that $\lim_{t\to\infty}t^{r-1}P\{X>t\}=0$, but that's obvious, because both $t^{r-1}$ and $P\{X>t\}$ approach 0 by themselves.

Comment: Hint: dominated convergence theorem.